# Web-service reference in NetBeans project

Tags: java, .net, web-services, netbeans, wsdl

I created **.NET console WS-host**. Now I'd like to create **Java WS-client** in **NetBeans** 8.0.

But I've faced to a problem. NetBeans returns an error in window: "*Problem with downloading wsdl or schema file. Check the URL, proxy settings or whether the server is running. URL: `http://localhost:8080/?wsdl`.*"©

Also output: "*Error: An I/O error occured. Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: `http://localhost:8080/?wsdl`*"©

I can open the URL in a browser. It's fine. Also **.NET web-client** works fine with the host.

Accidentally, I've used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in Chrome and IE. IE works fine and displays WSDL, but Chrome returns "*Error Code: 502 Proxy Error.*"©

Where could be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was resolved by changing of NetBeans Proxy Settings. I set it to No Proxy instead of Use System Proxy Settings.

Comment: Old question, but very useful reply for me! thank you Andrej

Comment: Does not work on NetBeans 8.2, still facing the same error

Comment: @MakariKevin Any progress on the issue? I am facing the same on Net beans 7